# Unrecognized argument oversubscribe when running mpiexec on WSL

Tags: c, mpi, mpiexec

When running the command: `mpiexec -n 4 -oversubscribe ./mpi01` on WSL 2 I get the following error:

```
mpiexec@John-Laptop] match_arg (utils/args/args.c:163): unrecognized argument oversubscribe
[mpiexec@John-Laptop] HYDU_parse_array (utils/args/args.c:178): argument matching returned error
[mpiexec@John-Laptop] parse_args (ui/mpich/utils.c:1642): error parsing input array
[mpiexec@John-Laptop] HYD_uii_mpx_get_parameters (ui/mpich/utils.c:1694): unable to parse user arguments
[mpiexec@John-Laptop] main (ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:148): error parsing parameters
```

This is my C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int size, rank;
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  printf("I am %d of %d\n", rank, size);
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `-oversubscribe` is an Open MPI option that is not valid for your MPICH (based) library.

Comment: am i missing a include then?

Comment: Nope, you are either using the wrong option or the wrong MPI library.

Comment: Believe it was the wrong library being used.